# Global variable undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making two bar charts in d3 on the same page and only the second bar chart is showing. So, the js file i've used for the second bar chart has an error that the global variable is `undefined` in one function.

```
var file_name = "story_fandom.tsv";
var visData;

//Step 1. Once every information is loaded to the browser
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Step 2. Load tsv file
    d3.tsv(file_name, function(error, data) {
        //If no data found: throw error
        if (error) throw error;
        //If the data is loaded successfully, now we are ready to draw things with D3.
        else{
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                data[i].stories = +data[i].stories;

            }   
            visData = data;
            console.log(visData);
            drawBar();

        }
    });
});

//Step 5. code drawBar
function drawBar(){

    $(".vis2").empty();

    var data = [];
    for(var i=0;i< visData.length;i++){
        temp={};
        temp.color = visData[i].color;
        temp.fandom = visData[i].fandom;
        temp.amount = visData[i].stories;
        data.push(temp);
    }
```

this is my js. the second js file is the same format except for another variable "favourites"

The global varialbe `visData` is showing `undefined` in the for loop of `drawBar()`. What is my mistake?

Heres the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/khyatijparekh/dmx2nun7/

Comment: Are you sure you are only calling `drawBar()` from within that callback, after you assigned to `visData`?

Comment: Instead of using a global variable, give `drawBar` a `visData` parameter and pass the `data` as an argument.

Comment: The error is still in the for loop in drawBar(). i dont understand why its happening, the other js file which isnt showing the bar graph doesnt have this problem. i tried passing it as a parameter, the error didnt go

Comment: what does your `console.log(visData);` say?

Comment: Did you verify that the content of `data` is not undefind?

Comment: My guess is you're missing the `stories` property in at least one of the objects in your `data` array

Comment: my console.log(visData) shows the data correctly but even then the visData variable is undefined. @faintsignal the data is undefined too.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is actually passing data. I'm guessing in one case the data object in the callback is undefined.

```
//Step 2. Load tsv file
    d3.tsv(file_name, function(error, data) {
        //New debug line
        console.log('data is' + data);
        //If no data found: throw error
        if (error) throw error;
        //If the data is loaded successfully, now we are ready to draw things with D3.
        else{
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                data[i].stories = +data[i].stories;

            }   
            visData = data;
            console.log(visData);
            drawBar();

        }
    });
```